# CRM Workflow Change Impact

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-4

I have made changes to a CRM workflow in a test environment. I plan on importing that modified workflow to the production environment and replacing the workflow in place. So I am wondering how that would impact the current flow (tasks and incidents) that are in place and relies on it. Any tips or process to publish the modified workflow would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a reference online that states this explicitly, however when you update an existing workflow, any workflow instances that have already started will run until completion *using the old version of the workflow*.

Comment: I found this to be true however I noticed that if a child workflow is also updated, the child workflow runs under the new updated version.

Comment: likely because that child workflow hasn't yet been invoked. when it is, system will run latest version. if child wf was also underway and waiting i would expect that it too would use the old definition.